# Nested json into dataframe with python3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to put a JSON result into a DataFrame using python3.

Here is the Json result I'm working with:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "2": {
            "status": "0",
            "problems": [],
            "sla": [
                {
                    "from": 1582066800,
                    "to": 1582116906,
                    "sla": 100,
                    "okTime": 50106,
                    "problemTime": 0,
                    "downtimeTime": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        "3": {
            "status": "0",
            "problems": [],
            "sla": [
                {
                    "from": 1582066800,
                    "to": 1582116906,
                    "sla": 100,
                    "okTime": 50106,
                    "problemTime": 0,
                    "downtimeTime": 0
                }
            ]
        }
   },
    "id": 1
}
```

So far, I 've been able to get the table for one entry:
`df = pd.DataFrame(mydata['result']['2']['sla'])`

Now I would like to have all entries in my table. Here is what i would like to get:

```
 hostid   from           to            sla     okTime    problemTime     downtimeTime
 2        1582066800     1582116906    100     50106     0               0
 3        1582066800     1582116906    100     50106     0               0
```

How can I proceed ?

Comment: Try https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html#pandas.json_normalize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to grab elements from the different levels you have above:

```
data = [{'hostid': key, **val['sla'][0]} for key, val in mydata['result'].items()]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Doing this before pandas will help if you dataset is large. Otherwise you can use pandas to flatten everything as suggested in the comments.